# Best way to inject Principal info into n-tier ASP MVC 5 using Unity DI and not using OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I'm writing an n-tier ASP MVC 5 app with Entity Framework in the data access layer. Bottom line is that I want an easy way to get the current user information, which is available in the Presentation Layer's HttpContext, into my Data Access Layer(repository), where it is not.  Obviously, this sounds like a job for my DI container (Unity 3).  My first reaction was to try creating a child container, which would be request specific, in the controller Action.  Because I went with the config and bootstrapping generously supplied by the good folks who support MvcSiteMapProvider, I ran into trouble because they have abstracted the DI container to handle several flavors and the container is read-only.  Then I stumbled across the Unity.Mvc PerRequestLifetimeManager which superficially sounds like a solution but there's kind of a dearth of information about it.  Before I get lost for days down the various rabbit holes, has anyone else been down this path and found a clean, semi-elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the PerRequestLifetimeManager is working well.  I expected a lot of trouble mixing the MvcSiteMapProvider's bootstrapper and other infrastructure with the Unity.Mvc NuGet package but so far it looks like they are very happy together.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my possible lack in understanding of the complexities of your project; but from a simpleton perspective some options for persisting entity audit info (last update datetime, user, etc.):
1. have a base class for your entities, define therein the audit info properties, set them in constructor or expose them to the app to set/override.
2. have a base class for your context, override SaveChanges, examine the entities being persisted and update their audit info (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but, the key point is that I'm trying to do this using the Dependency Injection (IoC) container.  I probably didn't do a very good job of explaining.  A mistake to submit a question when you're tired and frustrated.